# IIS 10 Sending Back Text only in Response.Write differently

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2016, iis-10

To support legacy clients, we had code in ASP.Net application on Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS 8.5.9600.16384 that would send back only "True" or "False" (no quotes):

```
   public partial class Authenticate : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Form["Login"] == "true")
            {
                var result = Membership.ValidateUser(Request.Form["Username"], Request.Form["Password"]);
                if (result)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Request.Form["Username"], false);
                }
                Response.Write(result);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

We installed a new Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.0.14393.0 and now it is sending back the value wrapped in html tags:

```
"<html><body><p>True</p></body></html>"
```

Why??  Doesn't do it on my development box or the older Win 2012 R2 server.  I can't find any info about this - we can't change all the clients, how can we ensure that this web page returns only "True" or "False" on Win 2016 IIS 10.0.14393.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

got it working, added ContentType as text/plain in headers like this:

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Response.Write(result);
        Response.End();
```